# If there a more concise way of accepting user queries in a django rest framework view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've read through the django rest framework documenation and tried to get the filter backend working with no success. My work around was to overide the get_queryset in the view:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        # create a var as a dict of the query parameters passed in by the user
        user_query = {key: value[0] for key, value in dict(self.request.query_params).items()}
        # this try block prevents the format argument used to return
        # json from being passed as a user query
        try:
            del user_query['format']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        queryset = Foo.objects.filter(**user_query)
        return queryset
```

My question is; is there a more concise way of doing it? or perhaps someone who can help me understand the django filter backend better.

Comment: Use [**`django-filter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html)

Comment: Thank you that was a major help.